# How to combine two regular expressions into one with different $1?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regular expressions with different $1. In the first part, there is a slash before $1, but there is no slash in the second part. How then to combine them into one expression?

```js
const url = 'http://localhost////example///author/admin?query=1212';
clean_url = url.replace(/($|\?)/, "/$1").replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1")
console.log(clean_url)
```

Comment: without using a function as replacement, it's not possible. I don't see any reason to do that.

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? This code far more readable than a complex regex with replace function.

Comment: @jabaa Because I have a nuxt redirect module that accepts a regex as a property key and I can't use the replace function

Comment: What module? There should be a better solution.

Comment: @jabaa @nuxtjs/redirect-module

Comment: @PeterSeliger it removes duplicate slashes from the path

Comment: Can't you use multiple redirects? `redirect: [{ from: '(.*)($|\?)(.*)', to: '$1/$2$3' }, { from: '(.*)([^:]\/)\/+(.*)', to: '$1$2$3' }]`

Comment: @PeterSeliger The 1st part adds a slash in front of the query parameters. If there are no query parameters, and there is no slash at the end of the line, then it is added

Comment: @nuxtjs/redirect-module also supports a replace function and a factory, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/redirect-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is asking about [@nuxtjs/redirect-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/redirect-module), you can use multiple redirects:

```
redirect: [{
  from: '(.*)($|\?)(.*)',
  to: '$1/$2$3'
}, {
  from: '(.*)([^:]\/)\/+(.*)',
  to: '$1$2$3'
}]
```

or a replace function

```
redirect: [{
  from: '.*(?:(?:$|\?)|(?:[^:]\/\/+)).*',
  to: from => from.replace(/($|\?)/, "/$1").replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, "$1")
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
const url = 'http://localhost////example///author/admin';
clean_url = url.replace(/($|\?)|([^:]\/)\/+/g, (x,y,z) => z ? z : '/' + y);
console.log(clean_url);
// => http://localhost/example/author/admin/
```

The `($|\?)|([^:]\/)\/+` regex matches

- `($|\?)` - Group 1 (`y`): end of string or `?`
- `|` - or
- `([^:]\/)\/+` - any char other than `:` and a `/` (Group 2, `z`), and then one or more slashes.

If Group 2 matches, the replacement is Group 2 value, else, the replacement is `/` + Group 3 value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to just "combine" these two regular expressions, but you can combine the tasks, as both are just inserting a single `/` with different conditions.

You can combine the logic with lookbehinds (which may not be available in every browser yet) and the expression is an abomination and I'd be careful about performance in production; But it is possible ;)

```js
const url = 'http://localhost////example///author/admin?query=1212';
clean_url = url.replace(/(?<!\?.*)(?<![:\/])(?:\/+|\/*(?=\?)|\/*$)/g, "/")
console.log(clean_url)
```